# Playing voice from server stream of nsdata using AudioUnit IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audiounit, gcdasyncsocket, remoteio

I am trying to build some kind of VoIP application in iOS. So far I have been able to successfully send the microphone data as a buffer from microphone to the server using `GCDAsyncSocket`. Now I need to play back the data I receive, which I am really confused about. I have looked online, but all I see is either playing back the audio file from remote or audio stream from a URL. I am actually receiving `NSData` regularly and need to figure out how to use those `NSData` to fill the audio units buffer list. I am new to C and finding it hard to get through it. This is where I get `NSData` from server.

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    if (tag == 1 ){
       //this is where I read password and stuff to authenticate

    }
    else{

        [self setUpAQOutput:data];//this should somehow initialize AU and fill the buffer
}
```

and in my `AudioUnitProcessor`, this is how I set up `AUnit` using [Stefan Popp's codes](http://www.stefanpopp.de/capture-iphone-microphone/) :

```
  //
//  AudioProcessor.m
//  MicInput
//
//  Created by Stefan Popp on 21.09.11.

//

#import "AudioProcessor.h"
#import "PTTClient.h"
#pragma mark Recording callback

static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) {

    // the data gets rendered here
    AudioBuffer buffer;

    // a variable where we check the status
    OSStatus status;

    /**
     This is the reference to the object who owns the callback.
     */
    AudioProcessor *audioProcessor = (AudioProcessor*) inRefCon;

    /**
     on this point we define the number of channels, which is mono
     for the iphone. the number of frames is usally 512 or 1024.
     */
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2; // sample size
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1; // one channel
    buffer.mData = malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 ); // buffer size

    // we put our buffer into a bufferlist array for rendering
    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;

    // render input and check for error
    status = AudioUnitRender([audioProcessor audioUnit], ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, &bufferList);


    // process the bufferlist in the audio processor
    [audioProcessor processBuffer:&bufferList];

    // clean up the buffer
    free(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData);

    return noErr;
}

#pragma mark Playback callback

static OSStatus playbackCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                 AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                 const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                 UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                 UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                 AudioBufferList *ioData) {

//does nothing
    return noErr;
}


#pragma mark objective-c class

@implementation AudioProcessor
@synthesize audioUnit, inAudioBuffer;

-(AudioProcessor*)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initializeAudio];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (OSStatus) playBytes:(NSArray*) byteArray {

    /**
     This is the reference to the object who owns the callback.
     */
  //  NSArray * byteArray = nil;
    AudioProcessor *audioProcessor = [[AudioProcessor alloc] init];

    // iterate over incoming stream an copy to output stream
    for (int i=0; i < [byteArray count]; i++) {
    //  AudioBuffer buffer = ioData->mBuffers[i];

        // find minimum size

        UInt32 size =  [audioProcessor inAudioBuffer].mDataByteSize;

        // copy buffer to audio buffer which gets played after function return
        memcpy(byteArray[i], [audioProcessor inAudioBuffer].mData, size);

        // set data size
        //buffer.mDataByteSize = size;
    }
    return noErr;
}

-(void)initializeAudio
{
    OSStatus status;

    // We define the audio component
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output; // we want to ouput
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO; // we want in and ouput
    desc.componentFlags = 0; // must be zero
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0; // must be zero
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple; // select provider

    // find the AU component by description
    AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // create audio unit by component
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &audioUnit);

        // define that we want record io on the input bus
    UInt32 flag = 1;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, // use io
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input, // scope to input
                                  kInputBus, // select input bus (1)
                                  &flag, // set flag
                                  sizeof(flag));
        // define that we want play on io on the output bus
    UInt32 stopFlag = 0;//stop flag 0 because we dont want to play audio back in device
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, // use io
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output, // scope to output
                                  kOutputBus, // select output bus (0)
                                  &stopFlag, // set flag
                                  sizeof(stopFlag));

    /*
     We need to specify our format on which we want to work.
     We use Linear PCM cause its uncompressed and we work on raw data.
     for more informations check.

     We want 16 bits, 2 bytes per packet/frames at 44khz
     */
    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate         = SAMPLE_RATE;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof( SInt16);
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof( SInt16);



    // set the format on the output stream
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &audioFormat,
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));


    // set the format on the input stream
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &audioFormat,
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));


    /**
     We need to define a callback structure which holds
     a pointer to the recordingCallback and a reference to
     the audio processor object
     */
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;

    // set recording callback
    callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback; // recordingCallback pointer
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;

    // set input callback to recording callback on the input bus
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &callbackStruct,
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));

     /*
     We do the same on the output stream to hear what is coming
     from the input stream
     */
    callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;

    // set playbackCallback as callback on our renderer for the output bus
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &callbackStruct,
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));

    // reset flag to 0
    flag = 0;

    /*
     we need to tell the audio unit to allocate the render buffer,
     that we can directly write into it.
     */
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &flag,
                                  sizeof(flag));


    /*
     we set the number of channels to mono and allocate our block size to
     1024 bytes.
     */
    inAudioBuffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    inAudioBuffer.mDataByteSize = 512 * 2;
    inAudioBuffer.mData = malloc( 512 * 2 );

    // Initialize the Audio Unit and cross fingers =)
    status = AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit);

    NSLog(@"Started");

}

#pragma mark controll stream

-(void)start;
{
    // start the audio unit. You should hear something, hopefully :)
    OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStart(audioUnit);
   }
-(void)stop;
{
    // stop the audio unit
    OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStop(audioUnit);

}

#pragma mark processing

-(void)processBuffer: (AudioBufferList*) audioBufferList
{
    AudioBuffer sourceBuffer = audioBufferList->mBuffers[0];

    // we check here if the input data byte size has changed
    if (inAudioBuffer.mDataByteSize != sourceBuffer.mDataByteSize) {
        // clear old buffer
        free(inAudioBuffer.mData);
        // assing new byte size and allocate them on mData
        inAudioBuffer.mDataByteSize = sourceBuffer.mDataByteSize;
        inAudioBuffer.mData = malloc(sourceBuffer.mDataByteSize);
    }
    int currentBuffer =0;
    int maxBuf = 800;

    NSMutableData *data=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    // CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
    // CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(ref, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);
    // NSLog(@"%@",blockBuffer);


    // audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize

    for( int y=0; y<audioBufferList->mNumberBuffers; y++ )
    {
        if (currentBuffer < maxBuf){
            AudioBuffer audioBuff = audioBufferList->mBuffers[y];
            Float32 *frame = (Float32*)audioBuff.mData;


            [data appendBytes:frame length:inAudioBuffer.mDataByteSize];
            currentBuffer += audioBuff.mDataByteSize;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }

    }

    [[PTTClient getDefaultInstance] setAudioBufferData: data];//This is call to send buffer data to the server

    // copy incoming audio data to the audio buffer (no need since we are not using playback)
    //memcpy(inAudioBuffer.mData, audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
}




@end
```

And finally this is the method to send audio data to server

```
-(void) setAudioBufferData: (NSData*) data{
   [gcdSocket writeData:data withTimeout:timeout tag:tag];
}
```

All of this work fine, and I can listen to the sound in my server that runs in Java. Now I need to figure out how to adjust this audio unit to play the `NSData` packets that I continuously receiving from the server (I have looked at some examples that play back remote file, which is not what I need. I need to play voice). The source is not the file but some one talking, so I am kind of confused.

Comment: This is not "C". "Objective-C" is quite different from "C" itself.

Comment: Ok, can you suggest the best way to achieve playback of voice.

Comment: are you implemented this if yes please share the solution i have same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Well presumably the audio data could become large so I would file-buffer it. Not sure the more elegant way but hey...the brute force methods in your code running at C++ level logic deter me a bit...

Is using

```
[NSData writeToFile:atomically:];
```

...helpful at all? Perhaps then use that file as the audio source passed to some more convenient Core framework?

2)The only other thing coming to mind is some form of local sockets. i.e. open a connection to yourself and supply that as a "remote source"

Sorry wish I knew more to be more helpful.

Comment: so every time i get the NSData, should i append it to the file? Could you please suggest me some more convenient core audio framework with sample code...i am very new at this all. I am sure there must be some more elegant way than what I have been doing.

Comment: ForPretty-Twilio,butIt'sPaidPerMinute.FromPersonalExperienceInCoreAudioPlayingSound as background/VoIP levelWillBeHairy.WhatIsYourIntendedAudience?CanYourJavaServerEncode HLS? This is a difficult problem...current sdk's are difficult too...Therefore SOMETHING must take up the slack

Comment: @jplego i want to play sound which is come from the socket data, so can you please provide me any sample code which you use because i do lots of research but did not found any good solution.